# Do security questions gate EFS for local Windows accounts?

Tags: user-accounts, password-recovery, efs

If the user forgets their account password and recovers the account by answering their configured [security questions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reset-your-windows-local-account-password-86912508-e584-37cc-86eb-6e9b0542b5ba), will they lose access to [EFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-encrypt-a-file-1131805c-47b8-2e3e-a705-807e13c10da7)-secured files? Or is guessing the recovery questions enough to gain access to EFS-encrypted files?

Is this configurable, and, if so, how is it configured?

I am asking this in the context of non-Domain-joined Windows 10 computers, with no especial backup options pursued (such as a [data recovery agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/windows-information-protection/create-and-verify-an-efs-dra-certificate)), with a local user account that's been created by the normal user setup wizard (i.e., not joined to a Microsoft account).

Comment: Because the password itself is important, I doubt it’s sufficient. // It should be easy to try this in a virtual machine.

Comment: If a user's password is **reset**, then the certificate used to encrypt the files, must exist in the certificate store or the files will be inaccessible.  You are warned that performing a password reset will make encrypted files inaccessible.  It does not matter how that password reset happens.  Unless a backup of the certificate exists, and is imported into the certificate store after the password is reset, the files will be inaccessible due to the encryption